# Spatialite - equivalent of ST_AsMVT

Tags: postgis, java, spatialite

I managed to make vector tile server in Java, using some libs, and simple code. In first example, I used PostGIS and example of it is this code:

```
public byte[] vratiNestoPostGis(Integer z, Integer x, Integer y){
    String q = """
      WITH mvtgeom as (
          SELECT
              ST_AsMVTGeom (
                      ST_Transform(geom, 3857),
                      ST_TileEnvelope(%1$d, %2$d, %3$d)
                  ) as geom, fid
          FROM
              simplified_land_polygons,
              (SELECT ST_SRID(geom) AS srid FROM simplified_land_polygons LIMIT 1) a
          WHERE
              ST_Intersects(
              geom,
              ST_Transform(
              ST_TileEnvelope(%1$d, %2$d, %3$d),
              srid
              )
              )
      )
      SELECT ST_AsMVT(mvtgeom.*, 'simplified_land_polygons', 4096, 'geom', 'fid') AS mvt from mvtgeom;
    """.formatted(z, x, y);
    SqlParameterSource src = new MapSqlParameterSource();
    return template.queryForObject(q, src, byte[].class);
  }
```

What I then wanted - is to move to Spatialite database, and there I had to use java libs:

```
public byte[] vratiNesto(Integer z, Integer x, Integer y) {
    template2.execute(
        "SELECT load_extension('mod_spatialite.dll');");
    String sql = """
        select fid,AsBinary(ST_SimplifyPreserveTopology(geometry,0.5)) as geom from nesto4326 where st_intersects(geom,st_geomfromtext(?,4326))
        """;
    try{
      String tile = TileUtils.parseXyz2Bound(x, y, z);
      List<Map<String, Object>> results = template2.queryForList(sql, tile);
      VectorTileEncoder vte = new VectorTileEncoder(4096, 8, false);
      for (Map<String, Object> m : results) {
        byte[] wkt = (byte[]) m.get("geom");
        Geometry geom = new WKBReader().read(wkt);
        TileUtils.convert2Piexl(x, y, z, geom);
        m.remove("geom");
        vte.addFeature("mapanesto", m, geom);
      }
      return vte.encode();
    } catch (ParseException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
  }
```

Is there any alternative to PostGIS `ST_AsMVT` in Spatialite, since I think that way my maps generation would be much faster than it is now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check what functions SpatiaLite has from the document http://www.gaia-gis.it/gaia-sins/spatialite-sql-latest.html. SpatiaLite does not have any native support for MVT.

Java bindings of GDAL and MVT driver https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/mvt.html might be useful, or GeoTools https://docs.geotools.org/stable/javadocs/org/geotools/mbtiles/MBTilesFile.html. Both options feel a bit heavy if you have written already your own code.

Also this old answer may be useful for you [Adding Geometry to a mapbox vector tile using java library](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/268333/adding-geometry-to-a-mapbox-vector-tile-using-java-library).

Comment: Thanks. I guess then I will have to make some pre-generation and tile caching. Or to see if there is some way to speedup this `st_intersects` operation - maybe to see if it is possible to have some index speed it up.