# Showing text on map tiles

Tags: openlayers, geometry, java, jts-topology-suite

I'm using Java to generate vector tiles, and so far this works OK. The thing that I do not know how to do is - write country names to the tiles.

I'm using currently `org.locationtech.jts` classes, and there I generate geometries using `Geometry`class.

What is the proper way to generate text (labels) that can show up on countries (on top of county polygons), and text that can be shown up on some streets etc. ?

Or is it better that I calculate centroids and then use OpenLayers to draw the text on top of countries?

What are the best practices here? Do they usually encode text directly into the vector tiles, or do they deliver this info separately?

Comment: Do you have some associated attributes to go with your geometries? I think we need to see some simple code

Comment: I'm just generating geometry for now, but I think I can deliver some attribute data (like country names). Code is as in this post (second part of the code related to SQLite). https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/407213/spatialite-equivalent-of-st-asmvt

Comment: I would create GeoJSON with desired text properties and then display text in OpenLayers. No need for centroids, OpenLayers will take care od placing.